# Setting and testing a variable in windows batch file

Tags: windows, variables, conditional-statements, batch-file

Creating a batch utility script on Windows 7 to invoke an executable.  It essentially works, EXCEPT that my second IF statement.  Tried a number of different things.

My intent is to invoke 'DoSomething' for each command line argument.  That part works!
The second IF statement prints a help message only if there no parameters given on the command line.  Well, that's the intent. That's not what it's doing.

```
@ECHO OFF

:Start
SET a_file_was_processed="false"
IF "%1" NEQ "" (
  SET a_file_was_processed="true"
  ECHO Extracting table %1 from database.
  DoSomething word%1 > output_%1.txt
  ECHO Finished extract table to file output_%1.txt
SHIFT
GOTO Start
)

if a_file_was_processed NEQ "true" (
  ECHO Invoke this script as: Extract_From_sdf  table_name1   table_name2
)
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried with these changes and seems to work as expected

```
@ECHO OFF

SET a_file_was_processed="false"
:Start
IF "%1" NEQ "" (
  SET a_file_was_processed="true"
  ECHO Extracting table %1 from database.
  rem --- DoSomething word%1 > output_%1.txt
  ECHO Finished extract table to file output_%1.txt
SHIFT
GOTO Start
)

if %a_file_was_processed% NEQ "true" (
  ECHO Invoke this script as: Extract_From_sdf  table_name1   table_name2
)
```

The first obvious error is the label :Start before the setting to false. 
Then to refer to the value of a variable you need to enclose the variable in %